# How to write into portable executable (PE) file while running?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, portable-executable

The problem is that I've a Windows executable (.exe) file, and I want its process to modify some values inside its image file while running, so the next time the program can continue execution from the point it stopped, what is the best way to do that?

Comment: modify the .exe file? or the in-memory image?

Comment: You want to do [Application Checkpointing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_checkpointing).

Comment: Give more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I suppose we're to assume that this executable is *not* signed.

Comment: This is not possible, the file is hard-locked by Windows while it is mapped to memory.  Forget about it, use a regular file to store state.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your application can use a file to store configuration and execution data.  Open the file on program start to get initial values and modify the values in the file as they are modified in the program.  This is certainly better than trying to modify the executable, if it's even possible.